# Qlikview V10.4 Threshold and Drill down issue

Tags: qlikview

I am using Qlikveiw version 10.4.  I am trying to apply a threshold to Sales amounts in a table chart.  Meaning, I want to display Sales above the threshold amount entered in the input box.  But also keep the dimensionality of the drill down for the following drill down dimensions... Product Name>Category Name>Supplier Name. LineSalesAmount is an expression.

So I have a chart table...

Product Drilldown group as my dimensions
LineSalesAmount (expression)

Apparently in QV v11, there is a new feature added to the chart wizard called dimension limits but how do I apply this same functionality in QV 10.4?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to achieve this using set analysis.

If you create a variable called `MinSalesAmount` and add that to an input box, you should then be able to filter the data in the chart by using a set analysis expression like this:

```
SUM({<LineSalesAmount={'>$(=MinSalesAmount)'}>} LineSalesAmount)
```

The chart will then only display records where the LineSalesAmount is greater than the value entered in the Input Box which is mapped to the `MinSalesAmount` variable.

You can find extensive information on "Set Analysis" in the Qlikview Reference Manual (`QlikView Reference Manual.pdf`) and the online help within Qlikview.